# Замена иконки бургера на стрелочку

Tags: java, android, xml, search, android-toolbar

Получилось синхронизировать состояние бокового меню с кнопкой бургера через ActionBarDrawerToggle. Т.е. иконка бургера превращается в стрелочку при появлении меню. 
Теперь мне нужно сделать так, что-бы при нажатии на кнопку поиска в toolbar изменялось состояние ActionBarDrawerToggle с бургера на стрелочку и обратно.
[image: Закрытый поиск]

[image: Раскрытый поиск неправильно]

[image: Закрытый поиск правильно]

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow,
            R.id.nav_tools, R.id.nav_share, R.id.nav_send)
            .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
            .build();

    toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,
            drawer,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    //noinspection deprecation
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);

    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.


    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);





    SearchManager searchManager =
            (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView =
            (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.app_bar_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(
            searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);


    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
            || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По хорошему этот бургер был создан специально в пару DrawerLayout-у, и привязывать еще что-то к нему не доброе дело. Надо бы свой написать, чтобы избегать всяких странных конфликтов.

А вообще можете ставить ему любое состояние методом toggle.onDrawerSlide(View, Float). Что там за View передается уже не помню, Float значение принимается от 0 до 1, где 0 это бургер, 1 это стрелка, 0.5 это на полпути с одного в другое.

Можете создать VelueAnimator из запускать изменение с 0 до 1, если покопаетесь в исходниках, найдете используемый интерполятор и продолжительность для "выезжания" NavView, чтобы их же использовать на анимации при активации поиска, иначе у вас при клике по бургеру будет одна скорость анимации, а при клике по поиску другая.

Еще надо решить что делать если юзер вытащил NavView жестом, когда выделен поиск и toggle уже в виде стрелочки. Если проигнорировать - будет скачок со стрелки на бургер и начнется анимация обратно к стрелке пропорционально выдвижению NavView

Comment: Благодарю. Благодаря вам понял в какую сторону копать и всё быстро заработало, как надо. Во view передал getCurrentFocus().

Comment: Может ещё подскажете как задать этой кнопки действие возвращения назад, когда она в состоянии стрелки?

Comment: в onOptionsItemSelected ловите нажатие на итем с id = android.R.id.home и обрабатывайте нажатие

Comment: Нет. Так почему-то не получалось.

Comment: Я разделил onSupportNavigateUp(). Поставил условие на 2 состояния